# Java Application loader error?

Tags: java, loader

I am new to the world of Java programming and I thought a good place to start would be working with a Private server based off the game RuneScape. I have been able to host these sources and make the client load in previous dates however, now when I try I am riddled with this error. I have took to many forums and many resources and the error still haunts me. Here is what the error is saying:

```
Error: Class291.method2751 client.init
   Loader.startClient
   Loader.doFrame 
   Loader.main
   Class481_Sub1
   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run
   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged 
   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass
   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass 
   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
   more
   Client\bin\Class481_Sub1.class
   java.io.FileInputStream.open0
   java.io.FileInputStream.open java.io.FileInputStream.<init> 
   sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader$1.getInputStream 
   sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream
   sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer 
   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass 
   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100 
   more | 
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class481_Sub1

error_game_crash
```

I have looked into class291.method2751 and there is no valid reason (that I can see) that should be giving me any type of errors. I figured this was a Java error so I uninstalled & re-downloaded Java (4 times now) and the error still occurs. I am running this in Eclipse IDE and am completely stumped.

Comment: `Class481_Sub1` class is missing, so make sure to include it to your class path.

Comment: Please teak the time to format stack traces properly. There's a reason they're logged vertically, one line at a time...

Comment: My apologies, as I stated i'm a beginner and i'm probably in over my head. I suppose ill scrap this until I have further knowledge.